# How to wrap slickgrid header row text and height of header row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, slickgrid

I have tried these following to wrap the text of slick grid header row.

```
  .slick-column-name {
      white-space: normal;  
   }
```

Following is for resetting height of header row : But it is not resetting.

```
 .slick-header-column.ui-state-default {
      height: 100% !important;
  }
```

If I reset it manually for example: height : 40px; then it is resetting.

I am using this slickgrid with bootstrap3.
Where I am going wrong?
Please help.

Comment: 100% of what? Does it's container have a height?

Comment: Can you add an image of the problem.

Comment: I have added class to this and assigned height. It is solved now. Thanks